# I need to remove a little space between my divided blocks

Tags: html, css

There is a little space between my two divided blocks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysU0R.png here you can see my problem. I've can’t figure out why the blocks act like this.

```css
body, main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 45px, wheat 0) top right,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 45px, wheat 0) bottom left;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Your link is 404.

Comment: Here you can see the problem space between blocks https://vimeo.com/741153606

Comment: @PeterJames perhaps I didn't fully understand your comment but on FF 104.0b10, Edge 104.0.1293.54 and Chrome 104.0.5112.81 on my rig there is no gap with my version, neither in normal nor zoomed view mode.

Comment: @SaschaM78 I could not see any gap on my Windows 10 PC in any of the browsers, but then I just scroll zoomed with the mouse wheel and when it hit 67% and 33% the gap appeared. Or simply go to the triple dot menu in Chrome top right and it's below bookmarks on the menu (sorry to mention that). It seems it must be something to do with division by 3.

Comment: @PeterJames I also saw the described gap in Edge and Chrome when using the original code but couldn't see if when the background is set to `background-size: 100% 51%;`. Do you also see a fine line at 33%/67% when you run my code snippet in my answer below?

Comment: @PeterJames good hint, with black it's easier to spot. In IE and Chrome I saw that with odd zoom factors the height jumps, which will most likely cause a problem in calculating the background size property. On 67% the size changes to `199.992px`, below and above it sticks to `200px`. As Firefox uses steps of 10%, this does not apply to it.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox there is no gap to be found, in Edge and IE it shows so it seems to be a sizing issue. Increasing the background size to 51% closes the gap also in Edge.

I'll try to find how the different browsers calculate background sizes.

```css
body, main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(-135deg, transparent 45px, wheat 0) top right,
    linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 45px, wheat 0) bottom left;
    background-size: 100% 51%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="container">
<div class="block">
</div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Such problems really do not exist in Mozilla Firefox, I wonder why...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, while when the container height is set to even number pixel, the line will be removed. When the container height is odd pixel, the line will be displayed.

The key factor should be `background-size: 100% 50%;` , so you could use scss round function to skip the rounding problem here.