# Why is there a 1 pixel space between navbar flex container border and flex item border?

Tags: css, flexbox

There is a weird 1 pixel border between the `flex` container border and the borders around my `flex` items.

I have put in my own `margin: 0`,  `padding: 0`, and `box-sizing: border-box` on `*`.

I have also tried it with a full CSS reset with no change.

I assume it is a browser issue.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: end;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grid-container">
  <div class="logo grid-item">
    <a href="#">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="about grid-item">
    <a href="#">about</a>
  </div>
  <div class="home grid-item">
    <a href="#">home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact grid-item">
    <a href="#">contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search grid-item">
    <a href="#">search</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Those are caused by your two 2px borders on the nav and the grid items

Answer (score 0):

I added some HTML and CSS to your code and ran it in jsFiddle.net in Chrome on Windows 10 and saw the problem you described. However, in Firefox there was no weird border with the border widths you gave (or with the ones I used). The SO code snippet I created below seems to work in Chrome and Firefox.

This probably needs further investigation with more permutations of border widths for the `grid-container` and `grid-item`. What browser, etc., did you test your code with and what was the browser zoom when you tested this?

I also checked this in Edge on Windows 10 at 100% zoom and it is clearly visible.

This may have something to do with odd and even values of border thickness and odd and even zoom percentages.

Please check [I need to remove a little space between my divided blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73417220/i-need-to-remove-a-little-space-between-my-divided-blocks#comment129656662_73417220) to see if your question is connected.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  justify-content: end;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: yellow;
}

div {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.logo {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  border: 2px solid red;
  background: orange;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.gc1 {
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.gc2 {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.gc1>.grid-item {
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.gc2>.grid-item {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<nav class="grid-container">
  <div class="logo grid-item">
    <a href="#">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="about grid-item">
    <a href="#">about</a>
  </div>
  <div class="home grid-item">
    <a href="#">home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact grid-item">
    <a href="#">contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search grid-item">
    <a href="#">search</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<br />
<nav class="grid-container gc1">
  <div class="logo grid-item">
    <a href="#">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="about grid-item">
    <a href="#">about</a>
  </div>
  <div class="home grid-item">
    <a href="#">home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact grid-item">
    <a href="#">contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search grid-item">
    <a href="#">search</a>
  </div>
</nav>
<br />
<nav class="grid-container gc2">
  <div class="logo grid-item">
    <a href="#">logo</a>
  </div>
  <div class="about grid-item">
    <a href="#">about</a>
  </div>
  <div class="home grid-item">
    <a href="#">home</a>
  </div>
  <div class="contact grid-item">
    <a href="#">contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search grid-item">
    <a href="#">search</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Below is an image of the code snippet running in jsFiddle.net on Chrome (and the weird 1 pixel border is clearly visible):

[image: jsFiddle.net showing weird 1 pixel border]

Comment: Sorry, this is my first question on this site. I was using chrome at 100% zoom. I also tested edge and firefox. Firefox is the only browser that doesn't have the issue. The thread you linked to discusses the same issue. They don't have an answer other than setting background-size to 100% 51%. Is that a viable solution?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Peter. I've decided it's not a huge deal, as a 4px nav border hides the 1px difference at 100% zoom. Otherwise, I can forgo a nav border, and opt for just a background.